# Retrofit 2 with RXjava adapter for API response in image/jpg Content-Type

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-glide

I have a get API that returns binary in the response and the Content-Type for the response is image/jpg

I want to display this binary to Glide

first question, How do I handle Content-Type image/jpg for the response Header

second question, How do I do receive the binary, convert it to be usable to glide?

I am using Retrofit 2.0.2, Okhttp3 3.5.0, RxJava 1, and Glide 3.7

Comment: you can convert your base64 to bitmap and then from bitmap to JPG and PNG or may b you can directly use it with glide if glide handles bitmap

Comment: it's not base64, its binary

Comment: base64 itself binary!

Comment: Try this in yout API: 
@GET("me/photo") Observable<ResponseBody> getPhotoUsingGET(); and then handle it onSuccess(): 
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(responseBody.byteStream());